# ZXing.BrowserMultiFormatReader() how to active scanning active area via border

Tags: javascript, jquery, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am implementing ZXing.BrowserMultiFormatReader() for scanning barcode on browser.

I am implementing this in jQuery/Java-Script, I want when i put relative barcode in front of camera it will highlight scanning area via border like PAYTM does or other scanning tool does. I juts want to show this to user that this Barcode is in focus.

My scanning work is working properly, i just want to display focus area to user.

Comment: Anyone here who can solve my problem...